# Validate hibernate entity-database mappings in spring boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I have an entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_user")
public class UserEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "user_id")
  private Long userId;
```

The database definition file which I roll by hand to a real database or with spring.datasource.initialize=true to in-memory h2 test (take a look at column name):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_user (
  uer_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
```

And application.properties definition related to db:

```
spring.datasource.initialize=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:sql/app-db-definition.sql
```

At startup of spring context (in tests too), I want to validate that entity columns mappings match db columns. How do I have to configure it?

Comment: I suggest a read of the documentation... http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-creating-and-dropping-jpa-databases... In short prefix with `spring.jpa.properties`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had an overriding version of hibernate in dependencies and misconfiguration to use it, so it skips properties :( 
M.Denium in the comment also right, that I forgot about `spring.jpa.properties.*`  prefixes.